# txt в SQL Python

Tags: python, sql, txt

Задача такая: Открыть txt файл и создать sql, каждая строка txt ячейка в sql
Но не мог понять почему разбивается по символам и забивает таблицу по вертикали

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('BD88.db')
cursorObj = con.cursor()

cursorObj.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl (adr text)')
con.commit()

with open("C:\\open\\5.txt",'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
     for line in file:
          s = line.strip()
          print(s)
cursorObj.executemany("""INSERT INTO tabl (adr) VALUES (?);""", s)
con.commit()
```

[image: Вот так]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('BD88.db')
cursorObj = con.cursor()

cursorObj.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl (adr text)')
con.commit()

with open("2.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        s = line.strip()

        cursorObj.execute("""INSERT INTO tabl (adr) VALUES (?);""", (s,))
        con.commit()
```